# How to write "Œuvres"?

Tags: fonts

How to write the following word in tex: "Œuvres"

I don't even know what word (language) is that. But I need to write in the bibliography a text typed in .tex

Comment: It's in french. Either you have it directly from the keyboard and type it with utf8 input encoding, or you type `{\OE}`.

Comment: You have "written" it in your question, twice. What's to stop you writing it the same way in your document?

Comment: [oeuvres](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/oeuvre) is also an acceptable spelling, in English at least.

Comment: @OrangeDog Certainly not acceptable in French: `oe` and `œ` don’t represent the same sounds.

Comment: @OrangeDog How can english accept a spelling from another language? It's a French word, so that an english dictionary is *wrong* doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @paul23 it's also an English word. The question says they don't know which language they're in.

Comment: @OrangeDog OP says "...I need to write in the bibliography...", so presumably they need to write the word in the exact way it appears in the title of something they're citing.

Comment: @Nathaniel and if the title is English, then "Oe" would be an acceptable substitute.

Comment: @OrangeDog not really. The point of a bibliography is to allow someone to find the reference. In the age of Google it doesn't matter so much, but in the old days a corrected spelling might have made it not come up in a catalog search, so the tradition is for bibliography entries to match precisely the spelling of the original, without any corrections or substitutions.

Comment: @Nathaniel assuming it's in a catalog system that can handle Œ...

Comment: Although it's frowned upon, "œuvre" is very commonly spelled with split "o" and "e" even in French, because 1. arguably "œ" is not straightforward to find on a keyboard, and 2. we're generally not taught ligatures at school when we learn to write. The same goes for "œuf", "œil" and so on. Not correct, but very common.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Œuvres is french and means "work" (as in "work of art"), you can input it directly or with the \OE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\OE uvres Œuvres
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see. You are showing that `Œuvres works`. ;-)

Comment: @Manoel Sorry if you already know this: You can also use Unicode and your system fonts, rather than legacy 8-bit fonts, by replacing `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with `\usepackage{fontspec}`. This requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: To clarify, _œuvre_ is a noun, so it's _work_ as in _work of art_.

Comment: @isanae yes good suggestion, I added it.

Comment: It's also an English word, usually spelled oeuvre.

Comment: @OrangeDog Œ is the same spelling as Oe, the difference is only typographical. "œ" is not a (new) french letter, it is a ligature :)

Comment: @A.G. go argue with [Thérèse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513928/how-to-write-%c5%92uvres/513931?noredirect=1#comment1299736_513928)

Comment: @A.G. But it's a lexical ligature, not a typographical ligature, so it does bear meaning and count as a different spelling.